# Get the value of browse(upload) field value in django/jquery before submitting the form

Tags: jquery, python, django, forms, django-models

I have a model like below

**models.py**

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='/media/')
```

I have to add some id, etc., attributes for designing purposes so

**forms.py**

```
class PublisherForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Publisher

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    super(PublisherForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['image'].widget.attrs = {'id':'selectedFile', 'style':'display: none;'}
```

**template.py**

```
<html>
   <body>
       <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'add_a_book' %}" method="post">
        {{book_form.name}}
        {{book_form.image}}

        <input type="button" value="Upload image" onclick="document.getElementById('selectedFile').click();" class="big_btn " />
        input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="window.location.href='{% url 'clear_image_for_pubsliher' book_id %}'" class="big_btn " />

        <input type="submit" value="submit">
       </form>
   </body> 
</html>
```

so for example if a user selects an image from the above browse(`Upload image`) button,
the image path will be something like `'image/akjsdhsa56453121/ping.png'`.

So is it possible to get the `image path('image/akjsdhsa56453121/ping.png')` in the `onclick javascript` function for `Upload image` above or else by writing seperate javascript function ? *** before the form has been submitted ***

because by using that value i will display the selected image instantaneously that the user has selected

Comment: You can do this nicely using the HTML5 file API, which allows Javascript to access the file in a `file` input element before it is uploaded to the server.

Comment: can u provide me an example please ?

Comment: Search for "HTML5 file API". There are dozens of articles and blogs on the subject.

Comment: actually some where it is told that, it is not possible to access the value of file input for security purposes, so posted the question here, and if u know a way , then please post it here